# Add gcm.jar in Eclipse IDE (Google Cloud Messaging)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem as:
I didn't find where can I get this Jar file gcm.jar? also where Can I put it ?.
Note I used Android 4.1.

Comment: The GCM files are located under your **android-sdk\extras\google\gcm**-folder.
For your Android-app, you'd want the "gcm-client\dist\gcm.jar".

Comment: I cannot find google in extras

Comment: go to your computer drive where you have put android-sdk\extras\google\gcm-folder, there you find google in extras.

Comment: **Just checkout the following link**

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293424/android-sdk-manager-gcm-library][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293424/android-sdk-manager-gcm-library

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start **SDK Manager** and scroll down to the section "Extras" and make sure you have installed **Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library**, if not, install the package.

The package will be installed in the directory "`your-android-sdk\extras\google\gcm\`"

Client code (for example to be used in Android app):
`gcm\gcm-client\`

Server code (where the Client connects to and registers it's regId):
`gcm\gcm-server\`

To add the gcm client-jar (gcm.jar) to your Android-project, copy it to the "**libs**"-folder in your Eclipse project and right click on the file and select **Build Path --> Add to Build Path**.

Comment: I installed Cloud Messaging for Android Library but I didnot find google\gcm in extras

Comment: What other folders do you have in your "\sdk\extras\google"-folder?

Comment: I had only \sdk\extras\ google play... also google analytic and Google Admob

Comment: Which version of SDK Manager are you using? Check in menu Tools -> About. Mine is "Revision 20.0.3".

Comment: I found gcm.jar in `/opt/local/share/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/dist`.  Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: hey Peter Gluck ..i also can't find gcm folder in sdk/extras.....can u tell me where is /opt/local/share/android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/gcm/gcm-client/dist file located...

Comment: @Durrat Did you install `Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library` from the *SDK Manager* ?

Comment: yes i did install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library from sdk manager and even if i open sdk manager it shows Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library Installed but there is no file in extras\google\

Comment: @Durrat That is really weird. Download GCM from Google at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/gcm_r03.zip unzip the file, rename the folder `gcm_r03` to `gcm` and move it into your `android-sdk\extras\google` folder, this is only a dirty fix, the SDK will most likely not be able to update it with a new GCM version, or removed the manually installed version, but other than that, it's the complete GCM package.

Comment: yeah..dats wierd...anyways i have downloaded the zip file ..wl give a try...thnks @chrkad

Comment: Yeh its works for me. It was really a weired thing. But now resolved. thnks@kaderud

Comment: but this  dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/gcm_r03.zip is not path to latest gcm.jar file.. can anyone provide latest gcm.jar file?

Answer (score 3):

The GCM Helper libraries (gcm.jar) has been deprecated.
The documentation for the library (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/helper.html)
now displays a messaging stating:

*The information in this document has been superseded by GCM Server and GCM Client. Please use the GoogleCloudMessaging API instead of the GCM client helper library. The GCM server helper library is still valid.*

Implementing a GCM server is documented here: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html
Implementing a GCM client is now documented here: [developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) (sorry, can't post as a link because I don't have enough rep).

Answer (score 3):

As on today's date, SDK Manager now has the option to "Show obsolete packages" (Packages->Show obsolete packages). This allows you to install GCM through the SDK Manager itself.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this link

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/gcm_r03.zip

when download completes extract the zip file, you will get three directories with names client side, server side and samples.

now open your SDK folder and create a folder named "extras/android" and paste all three folders here DONE!!

now whenever make a new project in project classpath using add external jar add gcm.jar.

[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293424/android-sdk-manager-gcm-library)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the Recored: I followed the steps provided by **chrkad** but I found the .jar file in the **DIST** folder and ***NOT*** in the **JAR** folder. After I found that out I saw that **Peter Gluck** postet that before.

**I hope that this could save some time to ppl having this issue! (took me 20 minutes)**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this package is now obsolete. In order to see it in SDK Manager I had to check "Show obsolete packages" in the "Packages" menu

See details from answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092848/4255980