# How to install Android GCM

Tags: java, android, adt

I can't find a way to install the Android GCM through the SDK Manager. I have managed to install the play services but in the extras folder I can't find the GCM.jar library.  The GCM is not listed in the SDK Manager checkboxes although I have made all the possible updates

Comment: You need only import play services library. GCM.jar is not required anymore.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html. Just follow this this link to set up Play services and implementing GCM

Comment: http://techlovejump.in/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/

Comment: Related QA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264761/add-gcm-jar-in-eclipse-ide-google-cloud-messaging

Comment: How about solving com.google.android.gcm imports ?

Comment: Which project you are using? From any article ?

Comment: a project developed with version 18

Answer (score 0):

You don't need GCM.jar. Only PlayServices library is required.
Refer: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is only [Google Play Services you need to setup](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup). [***Implementing GCM Client***](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/) is the complete source code, given by android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) .