# error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist - After migrating to Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-build

I have a problem with an old project which was developed in IntelliJ without Gradle. I wanted to migrate it to Android Studio and Gradle, but I am experiencing a lot of problems. Since the project was quite old, the old Google Play Services version was used. In Intellij I had just added libproject of the old gps to dependencies (google_play_services_5089000_r19) and everything worked fine. In Android Studio I managed to add other libraries by adding it as a library module and adding `compile project(':segmentedradios')` as a gradle dependency, but I just can't make gps library work. I've tried to add it as a module, but Android Studio says that "no module selected" after pointing to `libroject` library's directory. I also tried to add it as a gradle dependency, but I am keep getting errors like these:

```
error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist
error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
```

Despite I tried ~10 different solutions, the project still does not work. How to fix it?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my_package.app_name"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile project(':segmentedradios')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`GCMRegistrar` is not part of Google Play Services, but is part of the [now entirely deprecated](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9ui5Ywfgqeh) `gcm.jar` file.

You'll need to add `gcm.jar` to your dependencies if you'd like to temporarily keep using it until you migrate to Google Play Services' GCM implementation:

```
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for my app when I switched from Eclipse to AS.

Comment: @mvreijn I have the same problem you have encoutered please where can i download the gcm.jar file *

Comment: @Rodrigo I think I used the solution presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066114/1343553

Answer (score 2):

You can download `gcm.jar` by this path

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgcmjar.htm

or this

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gcm/gcm.jar.zip

After you download it, unzip it, it should have extention `.jar` not `.jar.zip`

Then copy and paste it to `libs` dir in your project

Then right click on `gcm.jar` and click on `add as lib`

That is it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these both lines in your build.gradle file of your application :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```