# GCM Android Studio migration from eclipse failed

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I am moving my `App Engine Connected Android Project` from Eclipse to Android Studio. It all worked on Eclipse of course. But Gradle isn't finding my `gcm` files. I pulled the appropriate dependency as

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
```

But my imports are still not found

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
```

Is there a new way of doing Notifications, is that why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, the C2DM package you are trying to import (which includes GCMBaseIntentService and GCMRegistrar) has been deprecated and you must now use the [GoogleCloudMessaging API](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#play-services) (now under Google Play Services).

Do take note that C2DM [will be shut down completely on July 30, 2015](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html).

Having said that, the answer to your question is that you can reference the gcm.jar file you used in Eclipse. The gradle dependency you put ("compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+`") will only work if you use the newer GoogleCloudMessaging API. If you'd like to keep your old implementation (at your own risk), please read ianhanniballake's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952873/error-package-com-google-android-gcm-does-not-exist-after-migrating-to-gradle).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a nice/complete example of the new implementation that I might refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here which may help you to solve this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765398/3364266