# Android Studio - App running not from latest saved project

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm having this problem since a few days.

I start Android Studio and Genymotion, open a project, run the app and everything is normal.

Next I edit my project by making a few changes, save the file, and then run it again but it doesn't run with my latest changes, but the old one before without the changes . (before I edited my project)

To correct this and make it run from the latest code, I got to close Studio and Genymotion and start again. But then again the whole cycle repeats.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling your old build and then run the project again from studio

Comment: Try saving the project after changes and. Sync the gradle, clean project, build project and then run ... problem is how you r running the build ... not the emulator I guess

Answer (score 1):

Click on make project as shown below in image and then run. It may help you.
[image: Click on make project then run. It may help you.]

Answer (score 0):

1. Please uninstall app from emulator.
2. try to Refresh and clear project instead of closing android studio or eclipse.
3. Make sure you are doing changes on right place.
4. after that run project again and hopefully you will be able to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below. It worked for me.

> Just go to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement ->
>   Instant Run" and just disable it. With this Android Studio builds from
>   scratch each time but it's better than not building it right.

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189496/2151304