# Android Studio does not save changes automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, autosave

After the recent update my Android Studio does not save changes automatically. For instance I added some info to logs and ran my app:

```
Log.i("test","starting app");
```

Then I just changed message to something like this:

```
Log.i("test","starting app: success");
```

When I ran my app again I still got "starting app" in logs. The same thing   happens with comments: I commented unused lines of code but I still get them working after restarting app. **Changes are implemented only after I restart Android Studio**. I know that it sounds stupid but I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: clean project , disable instant run

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147 answer. it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Goktay Kaykusuz's answer from another post:

> Just go to "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployement -> Instant Run" and just disable it. With this Android Studio builds from scratch each time but it's better than not building it right.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312900/android-studio-not-deploying-changes-to-app/35189496#35189496) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765223/android-studio-app-running-not-from-latest-saved-project) for more information, I believe the problems are similar.