# Android Studio No Longer Auto Saves Changes

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, autosave

I came back to Android Studio after a month of not using it and now it has stopped saving changes. Hot restarts simply rebuilds using the same code prior to any edits.

So I upgraded to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 Build AI 203.7717.56.2031.767800 built on Aug 26, 2021.

But the problem still persists. After much fiddling around IE: Flutter Clean, deleting build, restarting Android studio, I finally get the changes. But that makes getting anything done pretty impractical.

I saw this older thread whihc suggests I disable "Instant Run";

[Android Studio does not save changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792114/android-studio-does-not-save-changes-automatically)

But there is no "Instant Run" available under "File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment"

What has happened to Android Studio? How can I get it to save changes I make automatically before building?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems to have fixed itself. Changes are now saved.